# PharData open a large archive

Tags: php, large-data

I want to open in php a tar file of 45GB and about 5 millions files. I don't want to extract it. I just want to get the content of a single file(something about 10kb).

So far I have tried :

```
new PharData('tar file');
```

and

```
file_get_contents('phar://file.tar/single file');
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Is there a way to get the content of a single file from a large archive without reading the whole archive. Or something that takes less memory?

tar -xvf {tarball.tar} {path/to/file} is disabled by my host

Thanks

I found some answers where people were saying that this can not be done with tar. For tar you need to read the whole content in order to extract a single file.

My question is now, what format can you use in order to read a single file from a large archive without loading the entire archive.

Thank you

Comment: open 45GB to get 10KB? In PHP? Mate! You got something really f*ck up in your design...

Comment: the archive of 45GB does not contain only one file of 10Kb... It contains about 5 millions files. I just want to get a single file from that 5 millions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For tar you need to read the whole content in order to extract a single file

Not true. But compression adds complications when working with CLI tools. IIRC, [the PEAR tar package](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/download) can extract single files from gzipped tar archives without reading the whole file into memory.

Why do you need a 45Gb archive? Is it for deployment? If not then you really need to think about a different way of storing your data or switch providers.

Comment: $v_archive->extractInString('path to the file from the archive'); seems to work. But it takes more than 30 seconds to get the file. I will try with a zip archive without any compression. Thank you for your answer. I just want to store some old data on a shared server. The main server is on ssd and I don't have a lot a space. The problem on the shared server is that I can have only 250k files, so I am trying to find a good solution to just read from the archive

Comment: If its a limited number of files you're trying address then a better solution than a phar/tar file would be a database - SQLite? Then you've got indexed access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try a zip with alias and absolute path.

```
$p=new PharData(dirname(__FILE__).'/pharao.zip', 0, 'alias.phar', Phar::GZ);
$p->buildFromDirectory('temp');
```

If the Phar exists you don't need to new it twice. Just call:

```
echo file_get_contents('phar://alias.phar/existing.file');
```

I think this is fast - faster than swapping a million files with the memory. But ...

```
file_put_contents('phar://alias.phar/new.file', 'Hello world');
```

... is very slow. So very much slow that it is better to collect new files as usual and add them later at once.